# Jquery keyup method: Keeping results when returning from detail page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search form using jquery keyup and change methods, including ajax GET to php file to bring results. Each of this results have an icon to access a detail page (different page). The point is: when returning to search page I can see the form input with my written word but no results. My question is: how can I keep or trigger the same results according to the written word?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if the input has a value, if it does, trigger the keyup event (or whatever causes the results to show up.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#id_of_your_search').val().length) {
    $('#id_of_your_search').trigger('keyup');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dave. It worked with val()!='', but there is another problem. When returning from detail page, form keeps input value and results but: How can I start new search stopping the previous trigger? I put on click erase input and write new word, but results remain. In all cases I call the same ajax code.